# Optimize double enumerate loops

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to optimize this code:

```
for MajorKey,v in enumerate(data):
    for MinorKey,e in enumerate(v['events']):
        if e['displayed'] == False:
            del data[MajorKey]['events'][MinorKey]
```

The structure:

```
data : [{ //details,
         "events" :[ { //more details,
                      "displayed" : True},
                      { //more details,
                      "displayed" : False}
                   ]
       },
       { //...
       }]
```

`data` is a list. Each object in data has an 'events' array. Of those objects I want to delete those that have `display == false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't enumerate, and don't delete (*especially* if you're iterating over the sequence you're deleting from). Slice-assign a list comprehension instead.

```
for v in data.itervalues():
  v['events'][:] = [e for e in v['events'] if e['displayed']]
```

Comment: Thank you. With `.itervalues()` however I get: `'list' object has no attribute 'itervalues'`. And question, why is it more optimal to slice-assign? Is it processed faster or something like that?

Comment: @Diolor `itervalues()` is python2 syntax; it's just `values()` in python3.

Comment: @Diolor: Are you sure the structure in your question is accurate? You slice assign because then you don't have to care about what the position of the original value is.

Comment: @Diolor if `data` is a list, then just do `for v in data:` no need for `itervalues`. The way you have it written in your question it looks like `data` is a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you both. For the sake of correctness I updated the structure.